# PL SQL code to get possible diffs of data from two schemas and multiple views that have the same views and should have the same data

Tags: oracle

Using Oracle 11g I am trying to how to output the row(s) of new_table to a spool file and a sanity check on the approach I’m taking.

I can not do a select into using variables because I'm looking at many views and the fields are different for each.

When I do a select * after the one test view (where I did modify the base table to be different from the second schema) I get the desired result set.

But how can I get that to be output for dbms_output.print_line?  Or is there a better solution?

Thank you.

```
DECLARE

   sql_stmt varchar2(400);

   cursor c1 is SELECT view_name from all_views where owner = 'ownerx’ AND view_name like 'xxx_%' OR view_name like 'yyy_%' order by view_name;

BEGIN

    for i IN c1 loop
      sql_stmt := 'create table new_table as select * FROM schemaa.'||i.VIEW_NAME||' minus ' || 'select * FROM schemab.'||i.VIEW_NAME;

      execute immediate sql_stmt;

      dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
      -- Wish to list the result set from new_table via dbms_output.put_line()

      execute immediate 'drop table new_table';

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to reduce the question to printing the content of a variable table, you have to do some assumptions: for example you can have problems with CLOBS, BLOBS, XMLTYPE; also, you have to chose a default format for numeric and date columns, or simply rely on your settings for implicit casting.

Assuming you have a table with dates, numbers and strings, you can dynamically build a query that prints the table content.
For example, if you have:

```
create table someTable(a_number, a_string, a_date) as (
select 1, 'one', sysdate from dual union all
select 2, 'two', sysdate+1 from dual
);
```

You can print the content with:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vSQL varchar2(1000);
  3      vRow varchar2(1000);
  4
  5      cur sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7      select 'SELECT ' ||
  8              listagg(column_name, ' || '' - '' || ') within group ( order by column_name) ||
  9              ' from ' || table_name
 10      into vSQL
 11      from all_tab_columns
 12      where table_name = 'SOMETABLE'
 13        and owner = 'ALEK'
 14      group by table_name;
 15      --
 16      open cur for vSQL;
 17      loop
 18          fetch cur into vRow;
 19          exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
 20          --
 21          dbms_output.put_line(vRow);
 22      end loop;
 23  end;
 24  /
14-DIC-16 - 1 - one
15-DIC-16 - 2 - two

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You can refine this to handle the types of the columns, by checking `DATA_TYPE`, to apply the needed format to numbers, dates, timestamps, ...

As a aside, notice that a `MINUS` does not give the differences between two objects, but only the rows of the first one that are not in the second one. If the second view has more rows than the first one, `MINUS` will not tell you.
Of course this approach can work only if the views you are comparing have exactly the same columns.

Also, with dynamic sql you do not need to create a table to use for printing, but you could loop on the results of the `MINUS` (or whatever way you want to use to evaluate the difference).

Comment: Thanks Aleksej for the prompt reply.  I'll check it out.